# How do I add to the formula to separate into columns

Tags: vba, excel

How do augment this formula

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",TRIM(A1),1)),TRIM(A1),MID(TRIM(A1),FIND(" ",TRIM(A1),1),LEN(A1)))
```

to separate the data below into columns by symptom cause resolution

```
L=Cannot print in UNIX
```

Symptom:  Cannot print or plot in UNIX Cause:  Configuration issue

Resolution:  Escalate to the appropriate team  Escalation Path:  OEMM GIT Desktop  References:    Keywords:   ZEH  Created:

Comment: is all the text in one cell?

Comment: yes , the text is all in one cell I am trying to break it out into separate columns for instance the text is in cell b1 I am trying to break the text out into columns in cells c1, d1 and so on

Answer (score 0):

I like to get messy and complicated, but this can be done very easy Old fashion style.

```
hit Ctrl H 
replace your multiple line break chars (i.e. "1234") with a single wild char "~" or "}" are usually good
use Excel's feature "text to columns" to break the line based on your wild char separator. (ctrl +A, +E)
```

If you only have a single space " " to delimit your columns simply use text to column, check Delimited, and hit " " under Other separator, then Finish.
And of course, before doing this, you should copy the column (paste/special values on column C, and then breake it to keep the initial values on column B) :)
Hope this help.

**EDIT**

Here is a piece of code that I wrote up (in a bit of a hurry). This follows the example from above with user input for **column select** and the **string of chars** used to break the text. If you only need to use space as "text breaker" then enter " " in the second promt.
Usually I take time to "clean" the code but this is what 10 minutes produced:

```
Sub SplitColumns()

DestinationColumn = InputBox("Please enter the name of the column you on which you want to perform the split", _
                "Column Selection", "A", 100, 100)

Dim ReplaceRange As Range: Set ReplaceRange = ActiveSheet.Range(DestinationColumn & ":" & DestinationColumn)

SeparatorString = InputBox("Please enter the string of charatesrs used to define the split", _
                "String Definition", "anything goes", 100, 100)

' Please be carefull and check for anythinkg like "~" as it will produce errors if found within the cell text

Dim Response As Integer
Response = MsgBox(prompt:= _
        "Are you sure you want to split the text from column [" & DestinationColumn & "] based on [" & SeparatorString & "] ?" & vbNewLine & _
        "Once the macro is run, there is no Undo Option available(Ctrl+Z)", _
        Buttons:=vbYesNo)
If Response = vbYes Then
ReplaceRange.Replace _
    What:=SeparatorString, _
    Replacement:="~", _
    LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

ReplaceRange.TextToColumns _
    Destination:=Range(DestinationColumn & "1"), _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
    OtherChar:="~", _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End If

End Sub
```

Maybe I'll give this code another shot for a facelift (some other time).
Hope there's  no debuging to be done. I've tested it on Excel 2007. Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately the breaks can't be removed so standard text to columns won't work. I'm not sure about the "wild" card working either in this case

Comment: Didn't seem to work I may have inserted in the wrong place as the answer confused me somewhat

Comment: In this type of tasks I usually, double click a cell that contains the separator characters, copy this separator (/s) (either be it a random char, space, or anything else) and then, paste it in the "find what" field of the Ctrl+H (find and replace menu), Then, I usually fill the "replace with" field with "~" as it's uncommon to most texts used. This enables me to further use the text to columns Excel feature. Unfortunately the standard feature only allows one char as custom break under the Other tick box. I can look into a vba code by tomorrow if needed. Cheers.

Comment: Any vba code would be appreciated as this would help me out greatly to merger the two databases

Comment: I haven't heard back so should I take that to mean the time isn't available for further suggestions? if not that is perfectly OK I will pursue other avenues for a solution

Comment: sorry, totally forgot, good you followed up, will write this today and upload by EOD. ;)